# Spring KafkaEmbedded - problem consuming messages

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-test, spring-kafka

I have problem using KafkaEmbedded from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.kafka/spring-kafka-test/2.1.10.RELEASE

I'm using `KafkaEmbedded` to create Kafka broker for testing producer/consumer pipelines. These producers/consumers are standard clients from kafka-clients. I'm not using Spring Kafka clients.

Everything is working, the code works fine, but I have to use `consumeFromEmbeddedTopics()` method from `KafkaEmbedded` to make consumer works. If I won't use this method, the consumer does not get any messages.

There are two problems I have with this method: first, it needs `KafkaConsumer` as a parameter(and I don't want to expose it in class) and invoking this method gives `ConcurrentModificationException` when an object invokes poll using `@Scheduled`.

I'm using `auto.offset.reset` property so it's a different thing.

My question is: how to correctly consume records from KafkaEmbedded without invoking these `consumeFromEmbeddedTopics()` methods?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about that method, it simply subscribes the consumer to the topic(s) and polls it.

There is no reason you can't do the same with your Consumer.